# How to make Language filter at Azure Search Suggesting?

Tags: azure, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have multi language index at azure search, and also suggester by some field.
but suggester could return result from not current language is it any parameter to set language filter ?

```
  var url = $"{CloudSearchServiceSettings.SearchService}/indexes/{index}/{Docs}/{AzureSuggestUrl}{HttpUtility.UrlDecode(term)}&{SuggesterName}={SuggesterNameValue}&fuzzy={IsFuzzy.ToString()}&highlights={IsHighlighting.ToString()}&{ApiVersion}={CloudSearchServiceSettings.ApiVersion}";

            if (IsHighlighting)
            {
                url += $"&highlightpretag=<b>&highlightposttag=</b>";
            }

            return url;
```

Answer (score 0):

$filter works but latestversion_1 should be added !

```
[{"key":"$filter","value":"(language_1 eq 'en') and (latestversion_1 eq true)\n","description":""}]
```